# Add container DIVs around sections in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, count

I have piece of code below which nearly does what i ned it to do, except I need to modify it so that it adds container DIVs around each set of items within each row. The third snippet of code below shows the output i'm after. I've added  around the title groups and the content groups within each row. Please can someone add the missing part of the jigsaw?

1. The following PHP...

   ```
    <?php
           /* To get current page from query var */
           $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
           $args = array('post_type' => array('post'),'posts_per_page' => -1,'paged' => $paged);

            /* Create custom WP_Query */
           $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
           $post_ids = array();
           if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
               /* the wordpress loop */
               while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
                   /* Start my loop to get all post id in one array called "$post_ids" */
                   $post_ids[] = get_the_id();
               endwhile;
               /* end of the loop */
           } else {
               // no posts found
           }
           /* Restore original Post Data */
           wp_reset_postdata();


           $count = 1;
           $post_title = $post_content = '';
           foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) 
           {
               if ($count%5 == 1)
               {  
                    echo '<div class="row">';
               }
               $post_title .= '<div class="title">'.get_the_title($post_id).'</div>';
               $post_content .= '<div class="content">'.get_post_field('post_content', $post_id).'</div>';
               if ($count%5 == 0)
               {
                   echo $post_title;
                   echo  $post_content;
                   echo "</div>";
                   $post_title = $post_content = '';
               }
               $count++;
           }
           if ($count%5 != 1) {
               echo $post_title;
               echo  $post_content;
               echo "</div>";
           }
           ?>
   ```
2. ...currently outputs this HTML...

   ```
    <div class="row">
               <div class="title">title1</div>
               <div class="title">title2</div>
               <div class="title">title3</div>
               <div class="title">title4</div>
               <div class="title">title5</div>
               <div class="content">content1</div>
               <div class="content">content2</div>
               <div class="content">content3</div>
               <div class="content">content4</div>
               <div class="content">content5</div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="title">title6</div>
               <div class="title">title7</div>
               <div class="title">title8</div>
               <div class="title">title9</div>
               <div class="title">title10</div>
               <div class="content">content6</div>
               <div class="content">content7</div>
               <div class="content">content8</div>
               <div class="content">content9</div>
               <div class="content">content10</div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="title">title11</div>
               <div class="title">title12</div>
               <div class="title">title13</div>
               <div class="title">title14</div>
               <div class="title">title15</div>
               <div class="content">content11</div>
               <div class="content">content12</div>
               <div class="content">content13</div>
               <div class="content">content14</div>
               <div class="content">content15</div>
           </div>
   ```
3. ...but i want to add container DIVs to each section within each row like this...

   ```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="container">
               <div class="title">title1</div>
               <div class="title">title2</div>
               <div class="title">title3</div>
               <div class="title">title4</div>
               <div class="title">title5</div>
      </div>
     <div class="container">
               <div class="content">content1</div>
               <div class="content">content2</div>
               <div class="content">content3</div>
               <div class="content">content4</div>
               <div class="content">content5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="container">
               <div class="title">title6</div>
               <div class="title">title7</div>
               <div class="title">title8</div>
               <div class="title">title9</div>
               <div class="title">title10</div>
      </div>
        <div class="container">
               <div class="content">content6</div>
               <div class="content">content7</div>
               <div class="content">content8</div>
               <div class="content">content9</div>
               <div class="content">content10</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="container">
               <div class="title">title11</div>
               <div class="title">title12</div>
               <div class="title">title13</div>
               <div class="title">title14</div>
               <div class="title">title15</div>
      </div>
     <div class="container">
               <div class="content">content11</div>
               <div class="content">content12</div>
               <div class="content">content13</div>
               <div class="content">content14</div>
               <div class="content">content15</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   ```

Comment: Your output samples don't look any different, other than row wrapping. Can you provide a clearer example?

Comment: i've added `<div class="container">` around the title groups and the content groups within each row.

Comment: That's much clearer, and will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: Your query is extremely expensive, you are running 2 queries per post where you can do all of this with one query for 20 posts and not 40 plus queries for 20 posts :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
if ($count%5 == 0)
        {
            echo $post_title;
            echo  $post_content;
            echo "</div>";
            $post_title = $post_content = '';
        }
```

to

```
if ($count%5 == 0)
        {
            echo '<div class="container">';
            echo $post_title;
            echo "</div>";
            echo '<div class="container">';
            echo  $post_content;
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            $post_title = $post_content = '';
        }
```